# Question about system of t generators (Category Theory)

Tags: category-theory

I'm learning the Kashiwara, Schapira, "Categories and sheaves" p.258 Brown Representability Theorem. First Let's see the next images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the definition 10.5.1., the author asserts that a small family of objects $\mathcal{F} = (C_{i})_{i\in I}$ is a system of generator if "for any $X\in \mathcal{D}$ satisfies $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i},X) \simeq 0$ for all $C_{i} \in \mathcal{F}$, then $X \simeq  0$".
But why this statement true?

My first attempt : To show that $\mathcal{F} = (C_{i})_{i\in I}$ is system of generator,
fix a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{D}$ such that
$Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i},X) \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i},Y)$ is an isomorphism for all
$i\in I$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is triangulated category, by TR2, there exists a distinguished triangle $X \overset{f} \rightarrow   Y \overset{g} \rightarrow Z \overset{h} \rightarrow TX$.

Now fix $i\in I$. Then since $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ \bullet )$ is cohomological (c.f. the above image), we have a long exact sequence

$$ \cdots \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ X) \overset{f \circ} \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ Y ) \overset{g \circ} \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ Z ) \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ TX ) \rightarrow  \cdots $$

, where $f \circ$  is an isomorphism by the assumption for $f$. Now, in this situation, can we deduce $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(C_{i}, \ Z ) \simeq 0$ ? Then since $i \in I $ is arbitrary, by the assumption, we have $Z \simeq 0$ and from the underlined statement, $f$ is an isomorphism.

Is that true? Or anyway, can we get a distinguished triangle   $X \overset{f} \rightarrow   Y \overset{g} \rightarrow Z \overset{h} \rightarrow  TX$ such that $Z \simeq 0$ ?

Comment: Call "1" the condition of joint conservativity, and "2" the condition on $\hom(C_i,Z)=0$; you are proving that if "2", and if $f$ is such that $\hom(C_i,f)$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is an isomorphism; using "2", each $\hom(C_i,Z)$ is 0, thus $Z=0$, and thus, since $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \to 0 \to TX$ is a triangle, $f$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you..but why $Hom(C_{i}, Z)$ is $0$ from the condition 2? I'm stucked in the step.

Comment: You use 2 to deduce that $Z=0$. the fact that $\hom(C_i,Z)=0$ follows from the fact that there is a long exact sequence of abelian groups
$$ \hom(C_i,X) \cong \hom(C_i,Y) \to \hom(C_i,Z) \to \hom(C_i,TX) \cong \hom(C_i,TY) \to \cdots$$
this entails that $ \hom(C_i,Z)$, it is a general fact about les in an abelian category.

Comment: Ok, In fact, I also get if the last map $Hom(C_{i} , TX) \rightarrow Hom(C_{i}, TY)$ is at least injective, then by diagram chasing, $Hom(C_{i}, Z)$ is  $0$. But how can we show that injectivity? It is essential difficulty to show our goal.

Comment: I think you need to invoke the 5-lemma and find that $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \to Z \to W$ is exact, and $f$ is an isomorphism, then $Z\cong 0$.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I'm trying to use five lemma as you commented, but I still don't understand. Any way, I will continue. In fact, If for a given object $C \in \mathcal{D}$ there exist quasi inverse $G$ of $T$ such that $G(C) \cong C$, then by replacing ${C_{i}}$ by $C := \oplus{C_{i}}$, I could show that $Hom(C, TX) \to Hom(C,TY)$ is injective, and maybe game is over.