# About existence of quasi inverse $G$ satisfying $G(C) \cong\ C$ for given object $C$

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

My question is simple.

Let $T: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D} $ be an equivalence and $C$ an object of $\mathcal{D}$. Then is there a quasi inverse $G$ of $T$ such that $G(C) \cong C$ ?

This question is related to my previews question

[Question about system of t generators (Category Theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254450/question-about-system-of-t-generators-category-theory)

If the above question is true, then I could answer the liked question affirmatively by showing that $$Hom_{\mathcal D}(C:=\oplus C_{i}, TX) \overset{T(f)\circ} \to Hom_{\mathcal D}(C, TY)$$ is injective.

I can upload more detailed explanation if we needed.

Anyway, is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Just consider a discrete category $\mathcal{D} = 2,$ $T: \mathcal{D}  \to \mathcal{D} $ swapping the two objects. Then for a quasi-inverse $G$ and $C \in ob\mathcal{D}$ you need $GTC \simeq C,$ which in the absence of arrows between the two objects of $\mathcal{D}$ implies that $G$ is a strict inverse of $T,$ for which obviously what you want does not hold.

Comment: Wow, what's a simple example. Thanks. Perhaps can you help about my linked question if you have a time?